# Is there any existing Java library that allows you to do fast, in-memory lookups of zipcodes (bonus, state and city) from latitude/longitude?

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

I have seen many so-called "reverse geocoding" libraries in various languages; all depend on calling an external provider via REST or some similar method. However, you cannot call a REST provider if you must handle thousands of requests per second.

On the other hand, the problem should be simple to solve - CSV-based databases are available for free with this information. The issue is the time and cost of writing an efficient and well-tested in-memory search implementation, versus downloading or buying an existing one.

I can't find any after a lot of looking, but I can't believe there can't be one. Is there any pre-written library that does this?

This question:

[Fastest way to find the location(zip, city, state) given latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260572/fastest-way-to-find-the-locationzip-city-state-given-latitude-longitude)

came the closest, but essentially indicates how to write the solution, not that there is anything available off the shelf. But there must be some library everyone uses for this. A dozen people a day must have this problem.

Comment: @birryree, comments are for comments. If you want to bookmark the question, the use the favorite question feature (click the star).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spatial databases (e.g. Postgresql with PostGis) use algorithms which are fast in looking up data for given latitude/longitude information. As you want to use a Java library and have it in memory you could look at the [H2 Spatial database](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/H2+Spatial+Database). I have never used it, so I can't comment on its performance.

Edit: Hm, looking closer at the link I've provided shows that this is a planned feature... Personally I'd simply use Postgresql/PostGis (with or without Java as server frontend) and be done with it. If your server has enough memory it will still fit the "in-memory" requirement. Naturally it does not fit the Java library requirement. There is however [JSI](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/), which could be used in memory and with Java.

Comment: Setting up and maintaining postgres just to solve this problem would be impossible in my situation. :(

JSI looks quite promising! What everyone has are freely available lists of ZIP/city/state/etc. with their lat/long coordinates, rather than rectangles, so point-to-point rather than point-to-rectangle searching is not really appropriate. It may be adaptable... but still... having to adapt such a thing, making thousands of tiny rectangles? Is there really no prepackaged solution available on the market? I am astounded that neither I (nor apparently anyone else) can find one.

Comment: Well, the JSI library works perfectly well with points, just use a rectangle of zero size (i.e. set minY=maxY and minX=maxX). In fact it was originally intended to add 'native' support for points, but the performance was good enough using rectangles that it was never needed.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to JSI. also you can search for quadtree or rtree and java. + I've done some work but I now know that I could have done better and had not yet the time to implement these tricks: https://karussell.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/tricks-to-speed-up-neighbor-searches-of-quadtrees-geo-spatial-java/